# Convert html entities to UTF-8, but keep existing UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, html-entities, mb-convert-encoding

I want to convert html entities to UTF-8, but `mb_convert_encoding` destroys already UTF-8 encoded characters. Whats the correct way?

```
$text = "äöü &auml; &ouml; &uuml; &#223;";
var_dump(mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES'));
// string(24) "Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼ ä ö ü ß"
```

Comment: Perhaps use [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) instead? [Demo](http://ideone.com/zIJa8a)

Comment: works like a charm! can you make it an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: 7 years later :-) : Could you clarify that you’re talking about PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mb_convert_encoding()` isn't the correct function for what you're trying to achieve: you should really be using [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) instead, because it will only convert the actual html entities to UTF-8, and won't affect the existing UTF-8 characters in the string.

```
$text = "äöü &auml; &ouml; &uuml; &#223;";
var_dump(html_entity_decode($text, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8'));
```

which gives

```
string(18) "äöü ä ö ü ß"
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/zIJa8a)

Answer (score 0):

In my localhost I get `string(18) "äöü ä ö ü ß"` .

I think it's something related with your page encoding. Edit the file with Notepad++ and from the toolbar go to encoding and change to 'Encode in ANSI'. If it doesn't work then try with 'Encode in UTF-8 without BOM'.

Answer (score 0):

and if that still isn't working try this

```
html_entity_decode($html, ENT_QUOTES, 'cp1252');
```

This is what was needed on a Windows IIS system for things to start working correctly. [see source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163590/help-to-get-rid-of-html-special-chars-in-database)