# bash: convert html entities to UTF-8, but keep existing UTF-8

Tags: html, bash, command-line, utf-8

Just like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338277/convert-html-entities-to-utf-8-but-keep-existing-utf-8), I need to convert html entities (e.g. `&amp;`) to UTF-8 (`&`) while ignoring other UTF-8 characters. The difference is that in my case, I need to do this via the bash command line.

I can use a tool like `recode` and run `echo '&amp;' | recode html..utf-8` which converts over to `&` just fine, however with UTF-8 characters in the string, like in

```
echo 'Arabic &amp; ٱلْعَرَبِيَّة' | recode html..utf-8
```

I get:

```
Arabic & Ù±ÙÙØ¹ÙØ±ÙØ¨ÙÙÙÙØ©
```

which, naturally, is not what I need. It should look like this at the end:

```
Arabic & ٱلْعَرَبِيَّة
```

Is there a way to do this without a bunch of messy and seemingly endless regex? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perl one-liner:

```
$ echo 'Arabic &amp; ٱلْعَرَبِيَّة' | perl -CS -MHTML::Entities -ne 'print decode_entities($_)' 
Arabic & ٱلْعَرَبِيَّة
```

Requires the [HTML::Entities](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities) module, which is part of the larger [HTML::Parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Parser) bundle. Install through your OS package manager or favorite CPAN client.

Comment: Nice! Works out of the box on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when trying to recode a Portuguese text using `recode`. This problem occurs because `recode` assumes that the input text is encoded with [ISO-8859-1 (Latin Alphabet Number 1)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

To solve the problem I used `recode` 2 times in a sequence.

See this example in Portuguese:

```bash
echo 'Isto é uma simulação.' | recode --diacritics UTF-8..HTML | recode HTML..UTF-8;
Isto é uma simulação.
```

Note that I use `--diacritics` to ignore characters like `&`, `<`, `>`, `'`. It is very important to prevent the `&` character from being converted to `&amp;`. The documentation isn't clear, but you can see it in the [source code](https://github.com/rrthomas/recode/blob/4c4f347f15918117ceaac40c01747578999aba3b/src/html.c#L569).

In the first `recode` command, the letters with [diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) are converted to their correspondent HTML entities:

```bash
echo 'Isto é uma simulação.' | recode --diacritics UTF-8..HTML;
Isto &eacute; uma simula&ccedil;&atilde;o.
```

Note that `é` was replaced with `&eacute;` ('e' with [acute accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent)).

The second `recode` command converts the HTML entities to UTF-8:

```bash
echo 'Isto &eacute; uma simula&ccedil;&atilde;o.' | recode HTML..UTF-8;
Isto é uma simulação.
```

Note that `&eacute;` was replaced with `é`.

Your example would look like this:

```bash
echo 'Arabic &amp; ٱلْعَرَبِيَّة' | recode --diacritics UTF-8..HTML | recode HTML..UTF-8 
Arabic & ٱلْعَرَبِيَّة
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to diacritics workaround, re-encoding thru the intermediate (non-HTML) escaping works as well. The JAVA escaping (\uXXXX) fits for that.

```
echo 'Arabic &amp; ٱلْعَرَبِيَّة' | recode utf8..java,html..java,java..utf8  

Arabic & ٱلْعَرَبِيَّة
```